# NSNumber wrapping int, returning wrong int, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsnumber

I need to store an int in an array, and I tried this way, converting the int to an `NSNumber` but `integer` ends up being 136894816...  Can someone please help me with this?

```
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
        NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
        [array insertObject:num atIndex:0];

        int integer = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `NSNumber` is not an int. What you are retrieving in your current code is a memory reference. Try this instead:

```
int value = [[array objectAtIndex: 0] intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:integer];

    [array_name addObject:xWrapped];
```